# Programmatically drawn icon is pixelated on some devices

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, icons, android-canvas

I am creating an icon in code that displays great on most devices, but on some, it shows up all pixelated.  I have tried creating the icon in different densities and seeing if storing it’s file manually in the res folder for the densities would make different and it does not.

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// draw bitmap icon image using Canvas and store in database as BLOB
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap bmpBase = Bitmap.createBitmap( 120, 120, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
...
Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bmpBase );
...
canvas.drawCircle( x, y, radius, paint );

// convert icon bitmap to PNG and extract as BLOB to store in database
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bmpBase.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos );   
buffer = baos.toByteArray();


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// get icon BLOB from database as Bitmap and set in ImageView
// ------------------------------------------------------------
...
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(iconBlob);
Bitmap iconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

// Set ImageView to our icon bitmap
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
imageView.setImageBitmap(iconBitmap);
```

Layout for ImageView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_icon_first"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"